# How to synchronize QAudioOutput on multiple devices?

Tags: qt, buffer

I have an audio playing app that runs on several distributed devices, each with their own clock.  I am using QAudioOutput to play the same audio on each device, and UDP broadcast from a master device to synchronize the other devices, so far so good.

However, I am having a hard time getting an accurate picture of "what is playing now" from QAudioOutput.  I am using the QAudioOutput bufferSize() and bytesFree() to estimate what audio frame is currently being fed to the sound system, but the bytesFree() value progresses in a "chunky" fashion, so that (bufferSize() - bytesFree()) / bytesPerFrame doesn't give the number of frames remaining in the buffer, but some smaller number that bounces around relative to it.

The result I am getting now is that when my "drift indicator" updates, it will run around 0 for several seconds, then get indications in the -15 to -35 ms range every few seconds for maybe 20 seconds, then a correcting jump of about +120ms.  Although I could try to analyze this long term pattern and tease out the true drift rate (maybe a couple of milliseconds per minute), I'd much rather work with more direct information if it's available.

Is there any way to read the true number of frames remaining in the QAudioOutput buffer while it is playing a stream?

I realize I could minimize my problems by radically reducing the buffer size and feeding QAudioOutput with a high priority process, but I'd rather have a solution that uses longer buffers and isn't so fussy about what it runs on - target platforms vary from Windows 10 machines to Raspberry Pi Zero Ws, possibly to Android phones.

Comment: Maybe https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiooutput.html#notify ???

Comment: And more, we can calculate useconds (1000000 / (sample_rate / period_size * 2)) for "usleep" between writes to output buffer.

Comment: Thanks, but notify() just seems to be notifying when Qt has handed off data to the pulse audio (or other) buffer, nothing to do with how much data is buffered "on the other side" - and that seems to vary quite a bit...

Comment: Ok, how you think about (once) calculation for time between writes to any output buffer? This "constant" time say how long playing part of buffer. It can help you?

Comment: My problem is that I can only get so close to actually synchronized due to the lack of information.  If I try to sync within less than ~150ms, the chunkiness of the information means that my playback is always jumping around "chasing shadows" as it were.  If I just leave it lay as long as it's not over ~150ms out of sync, then it plays smooth, but can be significantly out of sync for a long time - like an echo when you hear both sources at once.

Comment: Once upon a time I read about the project of accurate sync for online stream between listeners, but now I can't find this article.